# How to run a batch file by FME Server

Tags: batch, fme-form, fme-flow

I created a batch file, which executes a .fmw workspace on FME Desktop. I want this batch file to get started by the FME Server. So I created a simple workspace with a SystemCaller transformer, which calls the .bat. 
Running that workspace on FME Desktop works perfectly. 
As soon as I upload and run the workspace to the FME Server the logfile returns following error:

```
SystemCaller: Failed to Execute `\\*my UNC_Path*\start_fme.bat'
```

I granted a full access permission to the server and used a UNC-path to the .bat. On other projects I'm already using UNC-paths on FME Server workspaces to local data in the same directory as the .bat, so the connection between server and network drives is definitely working.
Any ideas, what I might have done wrong or might have forgotten?

Comment: switch to a user account rather than Local System account for FME Server. see this link https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/362/workspace-fails-on-fme-server-when-using-unc-paths.html

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I checked into this and you should be able to get this to work as long as you surround the command in double quotes. For example:

```
""C:\Python27\python.exe" "C:\scripts\C119009.py""
```

I do think that in a case like this there's very little reason to not have the parent workspace run the worker on FME Server itself using an FMEServerJobSubmitter transformer. Having the parent use a SystemCaller to run a bat file to run the worker workspace on Desktop just seems an odd way of doing things.

Comment: + UNC paths needs a user account (rather than Local System account)

Comment: Thank you, but despite I surrounded the path in double quotes, it is still not working. The reason I need to run the workspace on Desktop is the lack of an internet connection on the FME Server. The workspace contains a geocoder, so I definitely need the web connection. The Server has the purpose of an directory watch and triggering the desktop workspace, as soon as a change was made.

Comment: I don't think the UNC path is the problem. I granted full access to the local system account and its working, when e.g. a reader on a server workspace is refering on a network drive. Why might the UNC path work with readers, but with SystemCaller transformer not?

Comment: Can you try using the SystemCaller to run a really simple command - for example something like cls or similar. Something that doesn't need an argument or UNC path. Let's see if we can get any command to work. Then try running a batch file locally to see if that works. I guess there are just a few steps to test before being able to say whether the UNC part is the problem. Edit: Actually hostname would be better than cls - just as simple but actually returns a value we can check.

Comment: ok, I tried several things: (test.bat: creates an empty .txt on specific path // start_fme.bat: runs a FME workspace: \\servername\c$\apps\FME\fme.exe \\servername\path\to\test.fmw) 

what works: 
- running the test.bat located on a network drive by FME Server. 

what does not work: 
- running the test.bat located on C: 
- running the start_fme.bat

Comment: I think the problem is the access to my local C: drive. 
FME License Server, FME Server Application Server and FME Server Database are running with local system user. FME Server Core and FME Server Engines with my admin user account, which has full access permission to C:/apps/FME. Any ideas for possible solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for the problem I specified above.
 
It's not exactly the answer to my previous question, so I won't mark it as solved, nevertheless I want to share with you a possible way, maybe it helps someone else. 
*Main goal:* A FME process should be started on desktop as soon as a change was made on a specific .xlsx-file. 
*Previous solution trial:* FME Server does a directory watch on that file, as subscription it starts a process with SystemCaller in it, which executes a batchfile on the desktop. 
*Cause of failure:* FME Server apparently does not have the permission to execute the batchfile.
**Workaround:**
I'm still using the directory watcher running by the FME Server, looking for changes made on the xlsx-file. 
As subscription the FME Serve creates a trigger.txt on my local directory.
Additionaly I created a monitoring task as powershell-skript, looking for that trigger.txt. Whenever the task gets triggered, it executes the batchfile executing the FME Desktop workspace. For sure that's not the most elegant solution, but it works.